# Trying to check if a value from one list appears in either a second or third list (MS Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three lists of data. I need to check values from the first list against the second and third lists, and if the value appears I need to return that value. Here is the current formula I am using:

```
      IF(MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$2001,0) OR(MATCH(A2,K2:K2000,0)),"",A2)
```

but I receive an error.

Might someone please explain why and how to fix it?

Comment: That's not a valid formula to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your `OR` operator is in the wrong place. From the look of your formula you don't wont anything to show if a match is found and if nothing is found `A2` should be shown.

Here's something that should work:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(MATCH(A2, $F$2:$F$2001,0)),ISERROR(MATCH(A2,K2:K2000,0))),A2,"")
```

The reason for the `ISERROR` function is because if the value is not found, an error will be thrown.

Essentially, this forumla says if the value is not found in either column F or K, an error will be thrown and therefore the value is not present in either column. Otherwise the value is present in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Search both ranges. If no match in either, return "", otherwise return A2.

```
=IF(AND(ISNA(MATCH(A2,F:F,0)),ISNA(MATCH(A2,K:K,0))),"",A2)
```